# Component mounted twice

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple component which is rendered by a click function, but it gets rendered twice, this is my code.

```
<SeeCompany
    :is="create"
    v-bind:companyId="companySelected"
    @closeChild="closeModule"
  />
```

when i clicked in the button i change the create value to 'SeeCompany' so it gets mounted, but it repeats the same component text twice on the screen.

```
<b-button block
    @click="create = 'SeeCompany'"
    class="m-sides"
    variant="outline-primary">
        Ver
</b-button>
```

here is the image:

[image]

EDIT: Here is the code in the mounted

```
export default class SeeCompany extends Vue {

    @Prop({ default: 0 }) private companyId !: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    private mounted() {
      console.log(this.companyId); --> This is consoling two ceros (0) and the passed value for instance = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `v-for` on one of the surrounding components? You say it's mounted twice but it appears to be there 3 times in the picture, could you clarify? What is the value of `create` before the button is clicked and why are you using `is` for what appears to be a `v-if` scenario? Try inspecting the DOM in the developer tools or the components in Vue dev tools to see if that sheds any light on where the duplication originates.

Comment: @skirtle actually, the mounted is logged three times, i have just update the question with my code, and no, there is no a loop surrounding the component. "is" in this scenario is the same as v-if, thanks for the replay

Comment: Is it possible you have `:is="create"` on some other components and they are also being converted to a `SeeCompany` when the value of `create` changes?

Comment: No, the create value is changed on some clicks, i have notice that i have the same when i mount some others components. :/

Comment: Could you inspect the relevant elements for those 3 components in the browser's developer tools and post a picture of what you see? Try to include the common ancestor in the picture if possible.

Comment: Actually, you was right pointing the use of v-if instead of :is, thats is the problem, because i have more components called with the same variable, so in order to mount it i was changing the value of that variable on button click, seems that is not working this way.

Comment: Look at the repo if you want, change the v-bind:is to v-if.  https://github.com/epileftro85/vue-repo

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I asked *'Is it possible you have `:is="create"` on some other components'*. Both `SeeCompany` and `SeeOther` have that attribute in `Home.vue`. Are you clear now what is happening and why? Or do you need further clarification about the problem and/or solution?

Comment: @skirtle if you could clarify it for me, it would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main uses for `is`.

1. Working around limitations in in-DOM templates.
2. Dynamic components.

For more information see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is.

We can ignore the former case as it isn't relevant here.

Typically the second case looks a bit like this:

```html
<component :is="childName" />
```

Here `childName` is a property of the component and determines the name of the child component to use. In your example you called it `create`.

The actual tag name used in the template doesn't really matter. It is common to use the dummy tag `<component>` for this purpose to avoid misleading future maintainers who may not immediately notice the `:is`. Whenever you see `<component>` you know you're in a dynamic component scenario.

When we talk about dynamic components it is important to appreciate exactly what we mean by 'dynamic' in this context. We are specifically talking about which component to use. We are not talking about determining whether or not to create the component in the first place.

In the code in the question the value of `create` is initially set to an empty string, `''`. This is then passed to `:is`. If you inspect the DOM you'll find that this creates a comment node. While this does make some sense I am unclear if this is officially supported. I've not seen this behaviour documented anywhere and I suspect you may be getting lucky by falling down an internal code path that's intended for other things. It is not something I would be confident relying on in future versions of Vue.

The specific code of interest is:

```html
<SeeCompany
  v-bind:is="create"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
<SeeOther
  v-bind:is="create"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

So if you inspect the DOM when `create` is `''` you should find two comment nodes.

When `create` gets set to `SeeCompany` this is equivalent to:

```html
<SeeCompany
  is="SeeCompany"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
<SeeOther
  is="SeeCompany"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

In turn this is equivalent to:

```html
<SeeCompany
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
<SeeCompany
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

The result is the creation of two `SeeCompany` components. The original `SeeOther` tag is irrelevant here. This is why, as noted earlier, the convention exists to use a `<component>` tag to avoid being misleading.

Of course this isn't what you actually wanted the code to do. I'm unclear what the target behaviour is so I'm going to cover a few variations.

If you just want to show the components conditionally you'd use `v-if` instead:

```html
<SeeCompany
  v-if="create"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
<SeeOther
  v-if="create"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

Usually you'd want `create` to be a proper boolean, `false` or `true`. So set the initial value to `false` with `@click="create = true"`.

Of course this would show both `SeeCompany` and `SeeOther` at the same time. That may not be what you want either. Perhaps you only want to show one at once. For that you might do something like this:

```html
<SeeCompany
  v-if="create === 'SeeCompany'"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
<SeeOther
  v-if="create === 'SeeOther'"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

Here the initial value of `create` should be a falsey value of some kind, possibly `''`, with `@click="create = 'SeeCompany'"` and `@click="create = 'SeeOther'"` on appropriate buttons.

If the props for the components are all the same, and especially if there are more than two components involved, you could try to simplify this using `is`:

```html
<component
  :is="create"
  v-if="create"
  v-bind:companyId="1"
/>
```

This is shorter but arguably not as clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this is why this platform is so great, you are so right, i ended use v-if="create === 'SeeCompany'", thank you again.